# Odoo11 - Force authentication of a web page

Tags: authentication, controller, odoo, odoo-11

I work under Odoo11 with the Python3 language.
When the person goes to a web page, I want them to automatically connect without going through an authentication page. Is that possible? And if so, by what means? Controllers, url to change?
I don't have any code to suggest, because I don't know where to start.

Thanks for your understanding and thanks for your help!

**EDIT :**
I have a list on the Odoo website visible to only one user.
If I sign in with another internal user, I don't see this list.

There are several people who need to access this list. The url in question will be given only to these people.
I just want to avoid them an authentication page. It is a request made by our hierarchy.

My idea was to call a function "to disconnect" from Odoo (in case they have an open session) then pass the connection parameters (hard for example) with the username and password but only for a url.

My use_case I will say,

Url access -> Disconnect Session -> Connect Odoo session with username and password with parameters in my controller -> redirection to this url

Thank you

Comment: Without authentication? It's good idea?

Comment: What is it you are trying to achieve by this

Comment: You need as portal user or as internal user ?

Comment: Saumil gauswami : No with forced authentication
Muhammad Yusuf : I have to edited my question
Paxmees : Internal User